# Reflection in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type doub = typeof(Doub);
        object result = doub.InvokeMember("Call", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, new object[] { });
    }
}

public class Doub
{
    public Collection<string> Call()
    {
        Collection<string> collection = new Collection<string>();
        return collection;
    }

    public Collection<T> Call<T>()
    {
        Collection<T> collection = new Collection<T>();
        return collection;
    }
}
```

I tried to call the Call method, but the program cannot figure out which method to call. Error: (System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: "Ambiguous match found). How can you call exactly the Call() method of the class?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/framework/invokemember-ambigousmatchexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different way to get the method to execute. For example, the `Type` object has a method called `GetMethod` with various overloads, you could use the one that allows you to [specify how many generic parameters the method has](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethod?view=net-5.0#System_Type_GetMethod_System_String_System_Int32_System_Type___), for example:

```
Type doub = typeof(Doub);
var callMethod = doub.GetMethod("Call", 0, new Type[] {});

// You need an instance of the object to call the method on
var x = new Doub();

var result = callMethod.Invoke(x, new object[] {});
```

Comment: This works great https://dotnetfiddle.net/CIUKBm.  +1

Comment: It works. Thanks